# Create an expanding image with CSS and div or span

Tags: css, html

I have a complex image cutted up in alot of slice.
You can see http://jsfiddle.net/yefQR/

```
<!--Force IE6 into quirks mode with this comment tag-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<style type="text/css">

body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
}

#framecontentTop, #framecontentBottom{
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 130px; /*Height of top frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white;
}

#framecontentBottom{
top: auto;
bottom: 0; 
height: 110px; /*Height of bottom frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white;
}

#maincontent{
position: fixed; 
top: 130px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 110px; /*Set bottom value to HeightOfBottomFrameDiv*/
overflow: auto; 
background: #fff;
}

.innertube{
margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
}

* html body{ /*IE6 hack*/
padding: 130px 0 110px 0; /*Set value to (HeightOfTopFrameDiv 0     HeightOfBottomFrameDiv     0)*/
}

* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
}

</style>



</head>

<body>

<div id="framecontentTop">
<div class="innertube">

<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c2"  style=" background-color:     green;position:absolute;  left:4px;  top:6px;  width:20px;  height:68px;  z-index:1;  visibility:visible; ">
</div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c3" style="background-color: yellow;     position:absolute; left:24px; top:6px;width:47px; height:68px;z-index:2; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c4" style="background-color: red; position:absolute;     left:71px; top:6px;width:165px; height:68px;z-index:3; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c5" style="background-color: black; position:absolute; left:236px; top:6px;width:62px; height:68px;z-index:4; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c6" style="background-color: pink; position:absolute; left:298px; top:6px;width:147px; height:68px;z-index:5; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c7" style="background-color: orange; position:absolute; left:445px; top:6px;width:311px; height:37px;z-index:6; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c9" style="background-color: cyan; position:absolute; left:756px; top:6px;width:108px; height:37px;z-index:7; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r2c11" style="background-color: white; position:absolute; left:864px; top:6px;width:27px; height:37px;z-index:8; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r3c7" style="background-color: DodgerBlue; position:absolute; left:445px; top:43px;width:8px; height:31px;z-index:9; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r3c8" style="background-color: Gold; position:absolute; left:453px; top:43px;width:355px; height:31px;z-index:10; visibility:visible;"></div>
<div id="screenshot%20tsam%20900r3c10" style="background-color: LightCyan ; position:absolute; left:808px; top:43px;width:83px; height:31px;z-index:11; visibility:visible;"></div>


</div>
</div>

<div id="framecontentBottom">
<div class="innertube">

<h3>Sample text here</h3>

</div>
</div>


<div id="maincontent">
<div class="innertube">

<h1>Lorem</h1>
<p>

Lorem ipsum 

</p>
<p style="text-align: center">Vestibulum  </p>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Id like to make :

1) the header image autoexpanding using the repeated-y css property of  DodgerBlue color and Orange div because thy are the only 2 part of image axpandible.
2) Is it possible to define a minimum size of header, and is possible to make the entire body minimum size based that size so the browser cant get smaller  an if the window get smaller, scrollbar is show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `min-width` in your css.  You can also define a `max-width` if you need too.